# Angularjs ng-controller with resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've ran into problem with ng-controller and 'resolve' functionality:

I have a controller that requires some dependency to be resolved before running, it works fine when I define it via ng-route:

Controller code looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'data', function ($scope, data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    }
  ]
);
```

Routing:

```
...
.when('/someUrl', {
        templateUrl : 'some.html',
        controller : 'MyController',
        resolve : {
          data: ['Service', function (Service) {
            return Service.getData();
          }]
        }
})
...
```

when I go to /someUrl, everything works.

But I need to use this controller in other way(I need both ways in different places):

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">*some html here*</div>
```

And, of course, it fails, because 'data' dependency wasn't resolved. Is there any way to inject dependency into controller when I use 'ng-controller' or I should give up and load data inside controller?

Comment: I can write you an example later. But in your case, have the Service returns a promise rather than actual data. Once it's resolved, retrieve the data in your MyController, that means your Service must have a method or property that returns a cached data. I hope that helps.

Comment: I came up with this for the same issue  http://jsfiddle.net/cnst530p/6/

Answer (score 12):

In the below, for the route resolve, we're resolving the promise and wrapping the return data in an object with a property. We then duplicate this structure in the wrapper service ('dataService') that we use for the ng-controller form.

The wrapper service also resolves the promise but does so internally, and updates a property on the object we've already returned to be consumed by the controller.

In the controller, you could probably put a watcher on this property if you wanted to delay some additional behaviours until after everything was resolved and the data was available.

Alternatively, I've demonstrated using a controller that 'wraps' another controller; once the promise from Service is resolved, it then passes its own $scope on to the wrapped controller as well as the now-resolved data from Service.

Note that I've used $timeout to provide a 1000ms delay on the promise return, to try and make it a little more clear what's happening and when.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{blurb}}</p><div ng-controller="ResolveController">Using ng-controller: <strong>{{data.data}}</strong></div>',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      })
      .when('/byResolve', {
        template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{blurb}}</p><p>Resolved: <strong>{{data.data}}</strong></p>',
        controller: "ResolveController",
        resolve: {
          dataService: ['Service',
            function(Service) {
              // Here getData() returns a promise, so we can use .then.
              // I'm wrapping the result in an object with property 'data', so we're returning an object
              // which can be referenced, rather than a string which would only be by value.
              // This mirrors what we return from dataService (which wraps Service), making it interchangeable.
              return Service.getData().then(function(result) {
                return {
                  data: result
                };
              });
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .when('/byWrapperController', {
        template: '<h1>Wrapped: {{title}}</h1><p>{{blurb}}</p><div ng-controller="WrapperController">Resolving and passing to a wrapper controller: <strong>{{data.data ? data.data : "Loading..."}}</strong></div>',
        controller: 'WrapperController'
      });
  })
  .controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "ng-controller";
    $scope.blurb = "Click 'By Resolve' above to trigger the next route and resolve.";
  })
  .controller('ResolveController', ['$scope', 'dataService',
    function($scope, dataService) {
      $scope.title = "Router and resolve";
      $scope.blurb = "Click 'By ng-controller' above to trigger the original route and test ng-controller and the wrapper service, 'dataService'.";
      $scope.data = dataService;
    }
  ])
  .controller('WrapperController', ['$scope', '$controller', 'Service',
    function($scope, $controller, Service) {
      $scope.title = "Resolving..."; //this controller could of course not show anything until after the resolve, but demo purposes...
      Service.getData().then(function(result) {
        $controller('ResolveController', {
          $scope: $scope, //passing the same scope on through
          dataService: {
            data: result
          }
        });
      });
    }
  ])
  .service('Service', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
      return {
        getData: function() {
          //return a test promise
          return $timeout(function() {
            return "Data from Service!";
          }, 1000);
        }
      };
    }
  ])
  // our wrapper service, that will resolve the promise internally and update a property on an object we can return (by reference)
  .service('dataService', function(Service) {
    // creating a return object with a data property, matching the structure we return from the router resolve
    var _result = {
      data: null
    };
    Service.getData().then(function(result) {
      _result.data = result;
      return result;
    });
    return _result;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <a href="#/">By ng-controller</a> |
  <a href="#/byResolve">By Resolve</a> |
  <a href="#/byWrapperController">By Wrapper Controller</a>
  <div ng-view />
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting to note that in the 'By ng-controller' version, after the first time it resolves, the wrapper service no longer needs to resolve again even when you change the route back (it's a singleton that just initialised the one time). The other two trigger the resolve all over again. 'By Wrapper Controller' could probably use the wrapper service instead of directly using Service to avoid the continual re-resolving...

Comment: Additionally, you could probably do a directive using a similar concept to the wrapped controller, which might be more powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new module inside which you have the service to inject like seen below.

```
var module = angular.module('myservice', []);

module.service('userService', function(Service){
    return Service.getData();
});
```

Inject newly created service module inside your app module

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myservice', function ($scope, myservice) {
      $scope.data = data;
    // now you can use new dependent service anywhere here.
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like a hack, but a beautiful one, and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or it's not. 'myservice' loads data only after controller code starts. But the idea of 'resolve' is to load data before controller code starts.

Anyway thanks for trying.
*sorry, looked into wrong part of code after editing*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the mechanism of the prototype.

```
.when('/someUrl', {
    template : '<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-template="some.html"></div>',
    controller: function (data) { 
        var pr = this;
        pr.data = data;
    },
    controllerAs: 'pr',
    resolve : {
        data: ['Service', function (Service) {
            return Service.getData();
        }]
    }
})

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.data = $scope.pr.data; //magic
    }
  ]
);
```

Now wherever you want to use

```
'<div ng-controller="MyController"></div>'
```

you need to ensure that there pr.data in the Scope of the calling controller. As an example uib-modal

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    resolve: {
        data: ['Service', function (Service) {
            return Service.getData();
        }]
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) { 
        var pr = this;
        pr.data = data;
        pr.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
    },
    controllerAs:'pr',
    size:'sm'
});
```

modal.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div ng-include="some.html"  ng-controller="MyController"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="pr.ok()">{{ 'ok' | capitalize:'first'}}</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

And now you can use $scope.data = $scope.pr.data; in MyController

pr.data is my style. You can rewrite the code without PR.
the basic principle of working with ng-controller described in this video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that Service.getData() returns a promise, MyController can inject that Service as well. The issue is that you want to delay running the controller until the promise resolves. While the router does this for you, using the controller directly means that you have to build that logic.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'Service', function ($scope, Service) {
    $scope.data = {}; // default values for data 
    Service.getData().then(function(data){
      // data is now resolved... do stuff with it
      $scope.data = data;
    });
  }]
);
```

Now this works great when using the controller directly, but in your routing example, where you want to delay rendering a page until data is resolved, you are going to end up making two calls to Service.getData(). There are a few ways to work around this issue, like having Service.getData() return the same promise for all caller, or something like this might work to avoid the second call entirely:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$q', 'Service', function ($scope, $q, Service) {
    var dataPromise,
      // data might be provided from router as an optional, forth param
      maybeData = arguments[3]; // have not tried this before
    $scope.data = {}; //default values
    // if maybeData is available, convert it to a promise, if not, 
    //    get a promise for fetching the data
    dataPromise = !!maybeData?$q.when(maybeData):Service.getData();
    dataPromise.then(function(data){
      // data is now resolved... do stuff with it
      $scope.data = data;
    });    
  }]
);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what is needed here. I wanted to use `resolve` functionality from route without routing, which is not possible. But here you described now `$q` works.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the problem using `ng-init` but came across the following warnings on angularjs.org

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So I started searching for something like `ng-resolve` and came across the following thread:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2092

The above link consists of a demo fiddle that have `ng-resolve` like functionality. I think `ng-resolve` can become a feature in the future versions of angular 1.x. For now we can work around with the directive mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

'data' from route resolve will not be available for injection to a controller activated other than route provider. it will be available only to the view configured in the route provider.

if you want the data to the controller activated directly other than routeprovider activation, you need to put a hack for it.

see if this link helps for it:

http://www.johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

Getting data in "resolve" attribute is the functionality of route (routeProvider) , not the functionality of controller.

Key( is your case :  'data') in resolve attribute is injected as service.
That's why we are able fetch data from that service.

But to use same controller in different place , you have fetch data in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Service:

```
(function() {

var myService = function($http) {
    var getData = function() {
        //return your result
    };
    return {
        getData:getData
    };
};
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
myApp.factory("myService", myService);
}());
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");
myApp.controller('MyController', [
    '$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.data = myService.getData();
    }
]);

//Routing
.when('/someUrl', {
    templateUrl : 'some.html',
    controller : 'MyController',
    resolve : {
        data: $scope.data,
    }
})
}());
```