# How to tell angular that a controller has been added? (loaded from a separate file)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have `index.html` main file and partial `view1.html` and I use `ng-route`. So I want controller `view1.js` to be loaded only when `view1.html` is accessed.  So I successfully loaded the file using `resolve` directive. Since javascript loads in background angular starts to parse `view1.html` and I get:

```
[ng:areq] Argument 'SimpleController2' is not a function, got undefined
```

How do I to tell angular that a new controller has been added, and it should parse `view1.html` only after applying the controller.

[Check this out](http://plnkr.co/edit/GTJJRAULNJpYYtIlJpA5?p=preview)

**main.js**

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

  demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            controller: 'SimpleController1',
            templateUrl: 'View1.html',
            resolve: {
                lol : function get() {
                    console.log('file is being loaded');
                    var fileRef = document.createElement('script');
                    fileRef.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                    fileRef.setAttribute("src", "view1.js");
                    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
                    fileRef.onload = function () {
                        console.log('file loaded');
                    }

                }
            }
        })
        .when('/view2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'View2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
});

console.log('config has been added');
```

**controller.js**

```js
console.log("file parsed");
demoApp.filter('myFilter', function ($sce) {

    return function (input, isRaw) {
        input = input.replace(/a/g, 'b');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    };

});

demoApp.controller("SimpleController1", function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
    $scope.names = [

        {name: 'Nick', city: 'London'},
        {name: 'Sick', city: 'Tokio'},
        {name: 'Brick', city: 'cellar'}
    ];
});
```

I'm new to angular I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26928924/3872976), [this](http://www.johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/) (how to apply files)
 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909525/load-controller-dynamically-based-on-route-group) (gave up with applying `$controllerProvider`) 
 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274809/angularjs-load-view-only-after-resource-has-loaded) (didn't succeed either) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) (couldn't make the whole thing work together) I'm not even sure that those described my needs. Please give me a clue what post I should dive deeper.

Comment: Need to use third party loader to do this. Is there a reason you feel you need to lazy load like this currently?

Comment: Like `$controllerProvider` ? I have 3 view and each of them has 1000+ lines of code, I don't want to load them in global scope. Another minus is that I don't want `main.js` to have mixed code from views. I want to keep it clear and readable. Do I have bad designed architecture?  Should I implement controllers only in `main.js` and inject functions they use in separate files?

Comment: If polluting the global scope is your only concern, you can  get a reference to your angular module using `angular.module('demoApp')` (without a second argument).

Comment: Also having 1000+ lines of code in a controller might be a sign that you aren't using Angular's Services, Factories or Directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check the existence of the controller without dry-running it with `$controller` and catching an exception, which is terrible thing to do.

Even then you will have hard time to register a new controller, because after config phase `app.controller` can't be used, and `$controllerProvider.register` is available only in config blocks.

You may look at existing solutions for lazy loading, i.e. [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). [Here is](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router) how it manages routes.